# React Multiple services dependent causes rerendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a react project. I wrote a script to get auth token to be passed to a custom hook in order to retrieve information. However, when I try to render this react component it would rerender itself to get the result. Here is the code:

```
const SpotifyLogin = () => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(getToken().accessToken);
  const albums = useSpotifyData(token);
  console.log("Rendering ------");
  console.log("Has album:" + !!albums);
};
```

Here is the custom hook useSpotifyData(token)

```
export function useSpotifyData(token) {
  const [albums, setAlbums] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    SpotifyRequester("me/albums", token).then((data) => setAlbums(data));
  }, []);
  return albums;
}
```

The console would give me this on render:

```
Rendering ------
Has album: false
Rendering ------
Has album: true
```

How can I resolve this? What might be causing this rendering issue?

I've tried using logging token before passing into the custom hook. It has data before its been passed in. I have no clue why the rendering is triggered.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The logs seem completely fine/normal/expected to me.

In case you are misunderstanding the logs here's what is happening:

1. `albums` state is initially undefined
2. `albums` is undefined on the initial render cycle
3. `"Rendering ------"` will log to console.
4. `"Has album:" + !!albums` will log to console. Coercing `albums` to a boolean will log out `false`, i.e. `"Has album: false"`.
5. The `useEffect` hook in `useSpotifyData` runs and enqueues a state update. This triggers a rerender.
6. `albums` is defined on the next render cycle.
7. `"Rendering ------"` will log to console.
8. `"Has album:" + !!albums` will log to console. Coercing `albums` to a boolean will now logout `true`, i.e. `"Has album: true"`.

Code:

```
export function useSpotifyData(token) {
  const [albums, setAlbums] = useState(); // 1

  useEffect(() => {
    SpotifyRequester("me/albums", token)
      .then((data) => setAlbums(data)); // 5
  }, []);

  return albums;
}
```

...

```
const SpotifyLogin = () => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(getToken().accessToken);
  const albums = useSpotifyData(token); // 2, 6

  console.log("Rendering ------"); // 3, 7
  console.log("Has album:" + !!albums); // 4, 8

  ...
};
```

Your question seems to be about getting this all down to a single render. The only way this would be possible is if you could ***synchronously*** set the `album` state when the hook is initialized/run on the initial render cycle. Since `SpotifyRequester("me/albums", token)` returns a Promise this isn't possible with the current code you've shared.